# Installing Apache MyFaces 2 on WildFly 8.2.0

Tags: jsf-2.2, wildfly-8, myfaces

I want to add apache myfaces 2.2.7 in WildFly 8.2.0 and use it as default implementation.

Can anybode please let me know where can I found installer jar for apache myfaces ?

I am following the link https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/StepsToAddMyFacesSupportToWildFly to add MyFaces support to WildFly.

As I understand correctly, I need to download install-myfaces-2.2.7.jar and then rename it to cli.

But where can I find this jar ? I couldn't find the jar on nexus respository as mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get this jar.

Following are the steps :

Download the source for [WildFly 8.2.0](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/archive/8.2.0.Final.zip).

Go to location : `<WILDFLY_SOURCE_ROOT>/jsf/multi-jsf-installer.`
Run below command -

```
   mvn -Djsf-version=2.2.7 -Pmyfaces clean assembly:single
```

This will create .zip file which should be renamed to .cli.

Please follow the link - [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DesignOfWildFlyMulti-JSFFeature)  for detailed description