# Deploying MyFaces 2.2.8 on WildFly 8.2.0

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2, wildfly-8, java-ee-7, myfaces

**Environment :**

JAVA EE 7

CDI

WildFly 8.2.0

MyFaces 2.2.8

**Issue :**

I am trying to run WildFly 8.2.0 with myFaces 2.2.8 as default JSF implementation. 
Installion is completed . The details for this are on another SO question :

[Installing Apache MyFaces 2 on WildFly 8.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230424/installing-apache-myfaces-2-on-wildfly-8-2-0)

When my application war is deployed on WildFly 8.2.0 , the following exception is thrown and deployment doesn't complete.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager from [Module "com.sun.jsf-impl:myfaces-2.2.8" from local module loader @736e9adb

(finder: local module finder @6d21714c (roots: C:\Users\xyz\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules,C:\Users\xyz\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.apache.myfaces.spi.impl.Tomcat7AnnotationInjectionProvider.initManager(Tomcat7AnnotationInjectionProvider.java:182)
    at org.apache.myfaces.spi.impl.Tomcat7AnnotationInjectionProvider.postConstruct(Tomcat7AnnotationInjectionProvider.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.injectAndPostConstruct(FactoryFinder.java:415)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:519)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:361)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:203)
    ... 10 more

I have searched for the issue on web and found out same problem here http://www.hivmr.com/db/3jsapc8j3xz3js1dsasjxjpkx37379cm , but no solution has been found.

**The issue can be described as :**

1) MyFaces uses Tomcat7AnnotationInjectionProvider for annotation processing which requires org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager which is not available.

2) One solution is to use CDIAnnotationDelegateInjectionProvider , but how to configure it in MyFaces is not known ?

3) How to hook MyFaces in WildFly so that JBOSS Weld can process annotations instead of MyFaces supplied class ?

Comment: maybe it is the same reason like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272510/migration-of-jboss-6-1-to-jboss-eap-6-3/57530328#57530328

Answer (score -2):

Wildfly uses Mojarra as their implementation choice of JSF. To use MyFaces you can follow their installation steps explained here [1]

---

[1] https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/StepsToAddMyFacesSupportToWildFly

Comment: Try it, step 2 is wrong in that wiki page. It was valid up to wildFly 8.0, not 8.1 and up!